# How to get all cities covered by a single zip code using Google Places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

Doing a query on a zip code that covers more than one city only gives one result (for example, 94608 covers both Emeryville, CA, and Oakland, CA only returns Oakland, CA. Does anyone know of a way to get all the cities covered by a single zip code in this scenario?

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=94608&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=94608&key=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D)

```
result: {    "html_attributions" : [],    "results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "Oakland, CA 94608, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.837959,
               "lng" : -122.2824021
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.850726,
                  "lng" : -122.267169
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.81711689999999,
                  "lng" : -122.3202479
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
         "id" : "2b00cb741193ededf6c66ed7e9d67a987a3d478f",
         "name" : "Oakland, CA 94608",
         "place_id" : "ChIJj4VwQUJ-hYARW-kxrTBdc-g",
         "reference" : "ChIJj4VwQUJ-hYARW-kxrTBdc-g",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }    ],    "status" : "OK" }
```

I tried doing a reverse geocode search on the lat long from this result, but it didn't give me any results with Emeryville, CA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using Places Text Search for this. Use Geocoding API instead:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=94608&key=YOUR_API_KEY

In postcode_localities you will see an array containing both cities.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geocoder#GeocoderResult